# Python subprocess sudo returns error: ERROR: ['sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\n']

Tags: python, bash, ssh, subprocess, sudo

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

HOST = 'host_name'
PORT = '111'
USER = 'user_name'
CMD = 'sudo su - ec2-user; ls'

process = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','{}@{}'.format(USER, HOST),
                        '-p', PORT, CMD],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

result = process.stdout.readlines()

if not result:
    print "Im an error"
    err = process.stderr.readlines()
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(err))
else:
    print "I'm a success"
    print(result)
```

When I run this I receive the following output in my terminal:

```
dredbounds-computer: documents$ python terminal_test.py
Im an error
ERROR: ['sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\n']
```

I've tried multiple things but I keep getting that error "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo". It works fine if I just do it through the terminal manually, but I need to automate this. I read that a workaround might be to use '-t' or '-tt' in my ssh call, but I haven't been able to implement this successfully in subprocess yet (terminal just hangs for me). Anyone know how I can fix my code, or work around this issue? Ideally I'd like to ssh, then switch to the sudo user, and then run a file from there (I just put ls for testing purposes).

Comment: Why `sudo su - ec2-user; ls` instead of just `sudo -u ec2-user ls`?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` is prompting you for a password, but it needs a terminal to do that. Passing `-t` or `-tt` provides a terminal for the remote command to run in, but now it is waiting for you to enter a password.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-tt', '{}@{}'.format(USER, HOST),
                          '-p', PORT, CMD],
                          shell=False,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("password\r\n")
```

Keep in mind, though, that the `ls` doesn't run until *after* the shell started by `su` exits. You should either log into the machine as `ec2-user` directly (if possible), or just use `sudo` to run whatever command you want without going through `su` first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using process.stdin.write("password") as you suggested, but I am getting: 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' "
when I run that.

Comment: Did you pass `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` as an argument?

Comment: Missed that, but now that just brings me back to my original output from the console. "ERROR: ['sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\n']"

Comment: See the update; I added an explicit newline to standard input and the `-tt` option to the `ssh` command. The password prompt for `sudo` does appear in the standard output, though, so you might need to check for that when reading from `process.stdout` (it should be the very first line, if present.)

Comment: After trying the code as written I get the following error: ERROR: ["Bad port '-tt'\n"]. I tried moving '-tt' in the process variable so it was after PORT or before  '-p' but that just caused the terminal to hang.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `sudo` to work without requiring a password. Just add this to `/etc/sudoers` on the remote server `host_name`.

```
user ALL = (ec2-user) NOPASSWD: ls
```

This allows the user named `user` to execute the command `ls` as `ec2-user` without entering a password.

This assumes you change your command to look like this, which seems more reasonable to me:

```
CMD = 'sudo -u ec2-user ls'
```